# Does every arrow in a thin category neccessarily have to be monic and epic by default?

Tags: category-theory, monomorphisms

In other words, will there ever be an arrow in a thin category that is not either monic or epic?

Comment: Can you explain what motivates you to think about this problem?

Comment: I am learning about category theory for the first time. I initially thought that every arrow that is both epic and monic will also be an isomorphism. However that is not the case in general. One of the counter examples given to refute such a claim is the category of Pre-orders, or also the category of Posets. These categories are called "thin" categories because every pair of objects will have only one real arrow between them. If two arrows go from an object A to object B, then they are actually the same unique arrow between A and B. Therefore, I wondered if every arrow will be monic and epic.

Comment: @user2407334, be careful not to get the category of pre-orders/posets (in which it is in fact true that arrows which are both monic and epic are isomorphisms) confused with a single preorder/poset seen as a category.

Comment: @MeesdeVries Thank you! I will try to keep that clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, arrows in a thin category are all monic and epic. The definition of monic or epic is an implication, which ends "... then $f,g: X \to Y$ are equal". Since any two arrows with the same domain and codomain are equal in a thin category, this holds, and thus the implication holds vacuously.